# WooCommerce custom shipping method appears in the wrong place

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a WordPress plugin with a custom shipping method copied from the [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/) – the only real change I've made was to add a default `array()` value for the `$package` argument of `calculate_shipping` to silence the error `Declaration of WC_Shipping_Method::calculate_shipping() should be compatible with WC_Shipping_Method::calculate_shipping($package = Array)`.

Weirdly, my new method appears at the top of the shipping settings. I expect it to appear in the dropdown of available methods when I go to add methods to my shipping zone. Can anybody spot what error I am making?

I've checked that the key in the `woocommerce_shipping_methods` filter matches the `$this->id` of my class, which was the problem in [woocommerce custom shipping method not appearing in shipping zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403220/woocommerce-custom-shipping-method-not-appearing-in-shipping-zone).

[image]

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Your Shipping plugin
 * Plugin URI: https://woocommerce.com/
 * Description: Your shipping method plugin.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: WooThemes
 * Author URI: https://woocommerce.com/
 */

/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 */
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function your_shipping_method_init() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method' ) ) {
            class WC_Your_Shipping_Method extends WC_Shipping_Method {
                /**
                 * Constructor for your shipping class
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function __construct() {
                    $this->id                 = 'your_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
                    $this->method_title       = __( 'Your Shipping Method' );  // Title shown in admin
                    $this->method_description = __( 'Description of your shipping method' ); // Description shown in admin

                    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
                    $this->title              = "My Shipping Method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

                    $this->init();
                }

                /**
                 * Init your settings
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @return void
                 */
                function init() {
                    // Load the settings API
                    $this->init_form_fields(); // This is part of the settings API. Override the method to add your own settings
                    $this->init_settings(); // This is part of the settings API. Loads settings you previously init.

                    // Save settings in admin if you have any defined
                    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
                }

                /**
                 * calculate_shipping function.
                 *
                 * @access public
                 * @param mixed $package
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function calculate_shipping( $package = array() ) {
                    $rate = array(
                        'label' => $this->title,
                        'cost' => '10.99',
                        'calc_tax' => 'per_item'
                    );

                    // Register the rate
                    $this->add_rate( $rate );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'your_shipping_method_init' );

    function add_your_shipping_method( $methods ) {
        $methods['your_shipping_method'] = 'WC_Your_Shipping_Method';
        return $methods;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_your_shipping_method' );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$supports` property of the `WC_Your_Shipping_Method` class you created is not set. This is why you don't see it in the **Add shipping method** section of the WooCommerce backend.

Below is an excerpt from WooCommerce's abstract `WC_Shipping_Method` class:

```
/**
 * Features this method supports. Possible features used by core:
 * - shipping-zones Shipping zone functionality + instances
 * - instance-settings Instance settings screens.
 * - settings Non-instance settings screens. Enabled by default for BW compatibility with methods before instances existed.
 * - instance-settings-modal Allows the instance settings to be loaded within a modal in the zones UI.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $supports = array( 'settings' );
```

So, to see the new shipping method, you'll need to change your class constructor like so:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->id                 = 'your_shipping_method'; // Id for your shipping method. Should be uunique.
    $this->method_title       = __( 'Your Shipping Method' );  // Title shown in admin
    $this->method_description = __( 'Description of your shipping method' ); // Description shown in admin
    // set supported features
    $this->supports           = array(
        'shipping-zones',
        'instance-settings',
    );
    $this->enabled            = "yes"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced enabled
    $this->title              = "My Shipping Method"; // This can be added as an setting but for this example its forced.

    $this->init();
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*

**USEFUL LINKS**

- [Creating a new Shipping method and exploring the Shipping method API of WooCommerce](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/creating-a-new-shipping-method-and-exploring-the-shipping-method-api-of-woocommerce/)

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thanks very much @vincenzo-di-gaetano, that did the trick!